# OnClick Listener on ImageView on Toolbar not working

Tags: android, android-imageview, toolbar, android-toolbar

I am trying to show Action Bar in starting of fragment but after some action i hide the **Action Bar** using `((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();` and then I make my toolbar visible using `toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` All works fine apart from image OnClick Listener on **toolbar**. My code

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/action_bar_home_button"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

In my xml and folowing in java ->

```
actionBar =((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();

    toolbar = (Toolbar)rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
    toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    back = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.back);
    back.setOnClickListener(this);
    back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Logger.i("onBack");
        }
    });
```

Function that makes Action Bar hide and toolbar visible ->

```
public void readFilterRealm(Boolean isShortcut) {
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
    activity.getSupportActionBar().hide();
    actionBar.hide();
    toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}
```

No Logs Are Printing.
But when i tried to add
`activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
 activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`
I am getting fatal crash 
`This Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor. Do not request Window.FEATURE_SUPPORT_ACTION_BAR and set windowActionBar to false in your theme to use a Toolbar instead.`

I need both toolbar and Action Bar so I can't remove any one. All help are appreciated thanks in advance (:

Comment: did you call `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`?

Comment: yes I tried with that also but nothing works!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code snippet:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) getActivity();
        activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        ImageView imageButton = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.back);
        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
}
```

**EDIT**

for setting the toolbar you need to add:

in manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"><!-- ADD THIS LINE -->
```

in res/values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Please see my edited question. Thanks for your time.

Comment: did you try the second way ?

Comment: `setSupportActionBar(toolbar);`...requires you to remove the actionbar and use toolbar instead...

Comment: But that gives me this error `Activity already has an action bar supplied by the window decor` but i did not want to remove **Action Bar**

Comment: i have edited the answer...add the theme to the parent activity of your fragment...

Comment: But this removes my Action Bar and that I did not want. My need is to show Action Bar in starting and then after some function call I want to hide Action bar and show Toolbar instead of Action Bar.

Comment: you can use custom toolbar for your action bar --in that way you can always use toolbar..anyway i don't find a way to use both of them in same activity..casue when u call `setsupportactionbar` to set up the toolbar it will throw that exception

Comment: Thanks For time @rafsanahmad007 can you tell me how to use custom toolbar (:

Comment: here is a good example: https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-App-Toolbar

Comment: if the answer helps..you can mark it as correct..thankx

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same problem. I was unable to do it using my java file, so what i did is in my xml file i wrote `android:onclick="trigger"`

and then in java file i made a method called `trigger`:

```html
void trigger(View view){
//code
}
```

This worked for me.